# How to launch settings page on real ios device using appium?

Tags: selenium, appium

I know that accessing built-in apps of real ios device is not directly possible. But we can access them using some launcher apps like for safari we have safari launcher. Similarly **can we have settings launcher app to launch the settings app** on real ios device. If so, where can I find the launcher app or if possible how can we create it??
Any other idea is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found an answer to this. We can create a settings Launcher app with the help of xcode and can handle all the elements in the settings page. Infact we can create launcher apps for all the native apps of the ios real device.

Answer (score 2):

try to launch to com.apple.Preferences

if not try this:

in the capabilities set app as setting:

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    ......
    cap.setCapability ("app" , "settings");

    driver = new IOSDriver(....);
```

it should do the work!

Comment: Iphone 5 & ios 9.3.4.
Error: Installing com.apple.Preferences failed.

Comment: I have tried this too. But this is also not working. Also this solutions will work successfully on simulator. But i need it to work on real devices.